# Php Memory Leak?

Tags: php, php-5.6

My overall question is: has anyone experienced this situation before in Php, and is it in any way normal?

I'm at my wits end; this is a graph of memory usage on our linux server:

[image]

This is a server running some php cron background processes. The small increases/decreases are cron jobs that seem to work well. The job runs, memory goes up, the job finishes, memory usage goes back down. This is "real" memory usage of the server, measured by a daemon process. The big jumps are a single job that is the issue. It runs, memory goes up, it finishes...but memory usage doesn't go back down. After a few hours of increases, the server gets angry and restarts.

We have tried everything under the sun that you'll find if you search "memory leak" here on stackoverflow, google, etc. From unset, to destruct, etc. This job loops through a few thousand records and creates/manipulates objects in each loop. Objects in a loop seem to be the majority of memory leak issues in php, based on the reading I've done over the past 3 days.

So my question is not really what might we try to sovle the issue, we have really tried everything we can find. My question is, if you have experienced this, and if so is there just maybe not a solution/is this some sort of bug in php 5.6 that there is just no way around.

I'm happy to answer detailed questions about what we've tried, but there is so much info on stackoverflow and elsewhere regarding "what to do" to fix the problem already that I thought I would ask something a bit different. Thanks.

Comment: You should look at your application to determine what the problem is. What is the job doing?

Comment: Have you been able to isolate which job isn't releasing memory?

Comment: Yes, we've isolated the job, removed everything from it but the one main thing it does, which is basically a loop and an object. As mentioned, we've tried everything we've found (unsetting, destructing, etc.), there is a lot of reading on this. I'm just wondering if anyone has actually experienced the same

Comment: So what exact metric does that graph shows?

Comment: @zerkms memory utilization % of an aws ec2 instance. After the problem job runs a few more times, memory hits 100%, and the instance shuts down. If we stop the job from running anymore, memory utilization will stay at whatever it is at indefinitely.

Comment: Have you checked on machine itself? `free -m`? http://www.linuxatemyram.com/ You always need to explore the server itself, not what external tools report.

Comment: I'll try that. This is an internal tool installed on the machine though, and when memory gets high it shuts down, so I'm fairly certain the reporting is correct.

Comment: Well, unless you tell what exactly it shows - you can only speculate, not know for sure. Memory management **IS** a very complicated topic, a lot of tools oversimplify it. If you want to find the real issue - first start dealing with real data not derivatives. And if what you said is true: that the memory is not reclaimed after the process quits (which is impossible, unless you have a kernel with a memory management bug, which is unlikely), then the graph certainly does not show what you think it shows.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of free -m. Currently the external tool is showing memory utilization at 84%, and free -m tells me: total=491, used=464, free=26

Comment: Check the second line (`-/+ buffers/cache`, or if you don't have it - the complete first line), and the link I provided http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: runing `top` should tell you what application is using the most memory.

Comment: Thanks, missed the linuxatemyram link. Just finished reading, buffers/cache shows: used=398, free=93. In the "when should I start to worry" section of that link, "available memory (or "free + buffers/cache") has enough room (let's say, 20%+ of total)", free memory is less than 20% of our total, correct? I can hit the cron job again and decrease it even further I suspect, and then hit it a few more times causing the instance to fail (shut down? not quite sure)

Comment: Now it's time for top as @Ibu told: open it and sort by RSS (RES)

Comment: Is the problem job exiting before being called again?

Comment: @SloanThrasher yes it is finishing completely before being called again.

Comment: If it is finished - the memory it's been consuming is reclaimed back to the kernel.

Comment: @zerkms top is showing httpd 5 times, each about 14%. What I mentioned earlier about "if I run the job again, I expect that buffer/cache free will continue to increase" is not true, it has remained the same

Comment: So, the cron job does not consume that lots of memory and does not leak?

Comment: Sorry I don't think I understand "If it is finished - the memory it's been consuming is reclaimed back to the kernel."  Why do all other crons, when finished show memory usage decreasing then?

Comment: Memory in linux is always mapped to some process (or kernel itself). It is simply impossible that the process quits but memory is not reclaimed back. If memory is consumed - it is always a process that holds the mapping.

Comment: Also, I don't know if this is allowed by stackoverflow rules (if not, mods please feel free to delete this comment), but I will donate $100 USD to the charity of your choice for help in getting this figured out :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139194/discussion-between-kayakinkoder-and-zerkms).